# How can I find the number of genus? (The Exact Meaning of genus)

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

In fact I haven't studied manifold theory yet. Only I know is fundamental concepts of the differential geometry. According to the Wikipedia, It said meaning of the genus is the number of holes of a surface. Other people said "handle" instead of "hole"

link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)

The  $\chi(M) $ is the Euler-Poincare characteristic of a surface $M$ (I.e. $\chi(M) =V-E+F$) in this post. According to the Gauss bonnet theory, $\chi(M) = 2(1-h)$ [$M$ is a closed surface].

I have a really serious problems for finding the $\chi(M)$ using the genus.

First example) As you can see there is a single hole on a sphere. Just relying intuitively thinking, the number of the handle, $h$, would be $1$. Then, $\chi(M) = 2(1-h)=0$. But $\chi(M) =1$ When I finding $V,E$ and $F$. What is missing point for this?

[image]

Second example) There are $4$-holes on the sphere(below picture). You would easily check there are 2 holes side of sphere. But there are also holes at the south and north poles. Finding the V,E and F I got the result $\chi(M)=-2$. But In my thought $h=4$, So $\chi(M) = 2(1-h) =-6$ [Surely the answer is $-2$ not -$6$]. I'm very confused.

[image]

As you can expected, I have a problem finding the number of genus(Or I don't know exact meaning of it.) What is the exact meaning of the genus? It looks like having many flaw just relying "the number of holes" How can I count genus for any surfaces?

Comment: The formula you're using is only for closed surfaces—surfaces without boundary. But if I understand your examples, they have boundaries. The first example has a circular boundary, right? (Sorry if my earlier comment was confusing; I misunderstood your question.)

Comment: In other words, that's not the kind of hole they mean; they mean the kind of handle in a torus, which you'll note is still a closed surface.

Comment: @BrianTung, O.K. You've understood what I meant. But The punctured sphere doesn't have a boundaries. If I understand right, That is boundaries at the point of manifold the not topogical.

Comment: @BrianTung,   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773444/why-does-a-once-punctured-sphere-have-no-boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Genus" is not really a well-defined concept except for a [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces) connected surface; "closed" means in particular without boundary, so strictly speaking it excludes your examples, which have boundaries given by the edges of the holes.

What is well-defined in much greater generality is first the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) and second the [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) or more abstractly the [homology groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)). Your first example, the punctured sphere, has Betti numbers $b_0 = 1, b_1 = 0, b_2 = 0$ and so it has Euler characteristic $\chi = 1$; it is not a closed connected surface, whose Euler characteristic is always even. So it does not have a genus at all.

Your second example, the sphere with $4$ punctures, has Betti numbers $b_0 = 1, b_1 = 3, b_2 = 0$ and so it has Euler characteristic $\chi = 1 - 3 = -2$. It, again, is not a closed connected surface so it does not have a genus.

A closed connected orientable surface of genus $g$ has Betti numbers $b_0 = 1, b_1 = 2g, b_2 = 1$ (note the $b_2 = 1$ here which does not appear in your examples) and so has Euler characteristic $2 - 2g$. But as we see with the second example, there are other surfaces which have the same Euler characteristic as such a surface but are not closed.

Some people will tell you that the Betti number $b_i$ counts the "number of $i$-dimensional holes" but personally I think this idea is more confusing than enlightening and I do not recommend thinking about things this way.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for answer. But I've known the punctured sphere has no boundaries. Link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773444/why-does-a-once-punctured-sphere-have-no-boundary

Comment: @kechanglee: there are two ways to puncture a surface, and neither of them produce a closed surface. If you remove a single point then there's no boundary but the surface isn't compact anymore. If you remove an open disk (which is what I interpret your pictures to mean) then the surface is compact but now it has boundary. The two variants are homotopy equivalent so they have the same Betti numbers and Euler characteristic, so I don't distinguish them carefully. The important thing is that neither of them are closed.

Comment: If I don't understand right, what is the exact meaning of a "boundary "?

Comment: @kechanglee: if you want a precise technical definition you can consult Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Manifolds_with_boundary). For surfaces, intuitively it consists of the "edges."

Comment: I've read the wikipedia's articles you suggested. Still there are some points I can't fix. The case of boundary  what I  suggested is 3 dimensional half space. But Any point on the disk and considering any open sets containing the point, That open set isomorphic with $R^{+}\times R$, Not the $R^2\times R$.  $R^2\times R$ is boundary for my case.   So conclusion is it looks like don't have boundaries. I'm very confused.

Comment: @kechanglee: I don't know what you mean about $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$; that's $3$-dimensional and I assumed we were talking about surfaces, which are $2$-dimensional. Can you clarify what you mean? Are you considering the *solid balls* here, rather than spheres (which are given by their surfaces)? That's a different question again. You're not talking about surfaces anymore in that case so they definitely don't have a genus.

Comment: I've confused Euclidean n dimension and n manifold. E.g.) A sphere is 2 manifold when I search for it.But I've regard it as 3 manifold. Because it is constructed in 3D euclidean figure. It is totally wrong. That's why I made nonsense question to you. And this will be final question. What is the meaning of n manifold? It is different concetps comparing the Euclidean dimensions.

Comment: Oh sorry. You don't need to answer my question. I've got it. Very Thank you! You saved my life!